# Get string from byte[] "string.equals"

Tags: java, string, byte

Im getting a string from a byte[] doing this:

```
byte[] data = packet.getData();
        String str = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

And when I show the string  with `println` , it looks ok. But Im trying to do a

```
if (str.equals("a")) {
               other stuff
            }
```

And when the string is "a" it never goes into the if. A friend told me that is because I have to "filter" the `byte[]` to recieve only the part that contains data, before converting it to a string. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: tip => "a".getBytes(); If it is always a make it constant also you didnt mention you need to test equals or contains

Comment: I don't see any issue with this. I just tried this and it works fine.

Comment: Check the length of the byte array (or the length of the converted string). I bet it is not 1

Comment: Check length and content of str.getBytes(). It seems to be not char[] {'a'}. BTW, usually such byte-oriented APIs use byte[] as a buffer and user have to use a part of the array with String str = new String(data, 0, packet.size(), "UTF-8");